# What does z* represent in statistics?

Tags: mathematical-statistics

Could somebody please give me an explanation as to what Z-star means for statistics, where it's used, and how to calculate it?  My book is very confusing and I don't really know what it means.  Even a link to a website would be helpful.

Main questions I need to answer:
What does $z^{∗}$ represent? What is the value of $z^{∗}$ for a 95% and 90% confidence interval? Include a sketch.

Thank you very much.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight I don't know how to post a picture, and the questions simply ask "What does $z*$ represent? What is the value of $z*$ for a 95% and 90% confidence interval? Include a sketch.

Comment: That depends on how it's previously been defined or used. There's no "standard notation" meaning of "$z^*$". I may well have used $z^*$ to mean several different things at different times. So $z^*$ might well (and likely does) mean different things in different books. Some books don't use it at all. If you found this in a book, flip back to earlier in the book, where it *first* uses it. (Another possibility: does this book have a 'notation' page, either near the start or the end?)

Answer (score 4):

It means the "critical value of $z$."

This is taken from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk#Mathematics):

> In statistics, z* and t* are given critical points for z-distributions
>   and t-distributions, respectively.

---

> I appreciate it but that doesn't really help as I have a huge
>   background in calculus where a "critical point" probably has a totally
>   different meaning. Maybe an example problem and answer?

Certainly. In hypothesis testing, e.g. comparing a mean to a fixed number, we used the data to generate a z-statistics, and then we will see if that z-value is at the extreme tails of a normal distribution that is based on the premise that the null hypothesis is true. If the observed z-value is more extreme than that "critical value," we will reject the null hypothesis.

The critical value depends on your preset type I error rate. Most of the time it's 5% (corresponding to a 95% confidence interval), and we will then make the left and right side 2.5% area under the normal distribution our "rejection zone." The value that defines the starting of that rejection zone is the critical value.

For instance, in a two-tailed test, the critical value for 95% is 1.96 (which means if your observed z-score is bigger than 1.96 or smaller than -1.96 you'll reject the null.) For one-tailed, it'd be 1.64 at the right OR -1.64 at the left.

Comment: I appreciate it but that doesn't really help as I have a huge background in calculus where a "critical point" probably has a totally different meaning.  Maybe an example problem and answer?

Comment: @Jeff, added some description. I hope it'd help.

Answer (score -1):

z* means the critical value of z to provide region of rejection
if confidence level is 99%, z* = 2.576
if confidence level is 95%, z* = 1.960
if confidence level is 90%, z* = 1.645

Comment: In light of (a) comments to an older answer concerning what "critical value" means and (b) the ambiguity concerning whether you are discussing one- or two-sided tests, it looks like additional clarification is needed here.